# Dado un Array de Objetos, crear una copia nueva y sumar cada objeto su clave:valor

Tags: javascript, next.js

Dispongo de un array de objetos como el siguiente:

```
[
    {
        "date": "Sep",
        "likes": 1073,
        "retweet": 137,
        "reply": 0,
        "quote": 41
    },
    {
        "date": "Sep",
        "likes": 39,
        "retweet": 3,
        "reply": 5,
        "quote": 1
    },
    {
        "date": "Aug",
        "likes": 3216,
        "retweet": 379,
        "reply": 0,
        "quote": 128
    },
    {
        "date": "Aug",
        "likes": 17425,
        "retweet": 1276,
        "reply": 0,
        "quote": 321
    },
    {
        "date": "Jul",
        "likes": 2434,
        "retweet": 223,
        "reply": 0,
        "quote": 110
    },
    {
        "date": "Jul",
        "likes": 7572,
        "retweet": 510,
        "reply": 0,
        "quote": 196
    },
]
```

Necesito sumar de cada objeto con la misma fecha (date) sus respectivos clave:valor quedando al final un array de objeto igual a este

```
[
    {
        "date": "Jul",
        "likes": 3073,  //Suma total
        "retweet": 1137, //Suma total
        "reply": 52,     //Suma total
        "quote": 51     //Suma total
    },
    {
        "date": "Aug",
        "likes": 39,
        "retweet": 3,
        "reply": 5,
        "quote": 1
    },
    {
        "date": "Sep",
        "likes": 12525,
        "retweet": 1137,
        "reply": 123,
        "quote": 134
    }
]
```

He estado probando con varias soluciones con reducer y map, pero no encuentro la manera de que salga.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra un [repro] de lo que has indicado en la pregunta que has intentado. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar `reduce` para recorrer el array y crear un indice por mes, así:

```js
const data = [
    {
        "date": "Sep",
        "likes": 1073,
        "retweet": 137,
        "reply": 0,
        "quote": 41
    },
    {
        "date": "Sep",
        "likes": 39,
        "retweet": 3,
        "reply": 5,
        "quote": 1
    },
    {
        "date": "Aug",
        "likes": 3216,
        "retweet": 379,
        "reply": 0,
        "quote": 128
    },
    {
        "date": "Aug",
        "likes": 17425,
        "retweet": 1276,
        "reply": 0,
        "quote": 321
    },
    {
        "date": "Jul",
        "likes": 2434,
        "retweet": 223,
        "reply": 0,
        "quote": 110
    },
    {
        "date": "Jul",
        "likes": 7572,
        "retweet": 510,
        "reply": 0,
        "quote": 196
    },
]

const result = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, item) => {
   if(!acc[item.date]) {  //Si no existe esa fecha
     acc[item.date] = item; //La creas con el primer elemento
   } else {
     //Sino, ya existe, entonces le sumas los nuevos valores
     acc[item.date].likes += item.likes;
     acc[item.date].retweet += item.retweet;
     acc[item.date].reply += item.reply;
     acc[item.date].quote += item.quote;
   }

   return acc;
}, {}))

console.log(result);
```

Luego al finalizar usas el `Object.values` para desechar el índice y quedar únicamente con los valores

Comment: te hago una pregunta acc es un array nuevo? cambia algo si en vez de poner el callback de reduce(acc,item) pongo reduce(item,acc)?

Comment: No, de hecho `acc` es un objeto, mediante el cual creamos el índice de meses, para luego al final convertir ese objeto en array mediante `Object.values`. El reduce (item, acc) no lo puedes cambiar, pues el primer parámetro es el acumulador (por eso normalmente se llama acc) y el segundo es el item que se está procesando.
El segundo valor que se le pasa a `reduce` (que en este caso es un objeto vacio `{}`) es el valor inicial del acumulador. Aquí puedes ver mas info de como funciona la función `reduce`: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: muchas gracias!

Comment: ahi entendi perfectamente tu codigo con la aclaracion

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por la rápida respuesta! Use reduce pero no lo habia planteado de esa manera me iba por las ramas.

Comment: Considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada, asi ayudamos a toda la comunidad. Saludos